# Angular 1 - Stay sign in - multiple tabs session

Tags: angularjs

**How to handle stay sign in with multi tabs session in angularjs-1.**

I am *storing id,token and staySignToken* in localstorage. So i can able to check that staySignToken is true or false.

I am not clearing localstorage data when user close the tab or window.

If staySignToken is true and have local storage data means, I will redirect to dashboard page.

If staySignToken is false, I will redirect to login page at first time. 
If user logged in successfully with staySignToken-false condition, and tries login page in another tabs means we have to redirect to dashboard page.

Answer (score 1):

```
appdash.factory('multitab', function ($localStorage, $sessionStorage, $rootScope, $window) {
      --your statement----
})
```

Create the factory and write your session inside it.